# Can i programming on excel 14 and work on excel 12?

Tags: vb.net, excel

i want to make a vbnet program which will write and read in excel
i install excel 2010 so i add "Excel 14"
but if i want the application work on 2007 and 2010 then i must programming the application on excel 2007 or excel 2010?

Comment: Most of 2010 should be compatible with 2007. If you want it to work on both you may need to add reference to both Excel 14 and Excel 12. You may get some errors though, in which case you could just write separate subroutines for those particular cases.

Answer (score 0):

With improvements in each release there are new language formats that come available.  When writing VBA it is a good practice to write your code for the lowest version of Excel that any user will have.  Many of the new features are very cool for the newer versions of Excel and VBA however will foce a debug if run on an older version of Excel. I try to write in the previous version of excel just in case a user does not have the compatable programming to run the newer code.